# How to sort input in a python age sorting program

Tags: python

I just made a program where you can type in your name and your age and it is supposed to sort people for their age from least to greatest. This is my code so far:

```
student_ages = {}

polling_for_age_active = True

while polling_for_age_active:
    name = input("\nWhat is your name?")
    response = input("How old are you?")
    response = int()
    student_ages[name] = response

    repeat = input("Are there any other people to go? (yes\no)")
    if repeat == 'no':
        polling_for_age_active = False

print("\n----Ages(from least to greatest)----")
for name, response in student_ages.items():
    response.sort()
    print(name + " is " + response + " years old.")
```

When I run the code, the shell says that the `int` object cannot be sorted. Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this, or even improve it? Thanks.

Comment: `response = int()` doesn't cast anything, change it to `response = int(response)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple problems with your program. But the main design issue is that you are using a dictionary which is an unordered collection, and when you call `response.sort()` that is just trying to sort the individual item which doesn't do anything (you can't sort an integer).

What you can do instead is convert the dictionary items to a list which is sorted and then print that list out. We can store the items as tuples so it contains both the name and age data in the list.

```
sorted_list = sorted(student_ages.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1]) # Makes a list of tuples sorted by the values
# Loop through sorted_list of tuples
for name, age in sorted_list:
    print("{} is {} years old".format(name, age))
```

---

The other small problem with your program is that you are not properly taking in inputs and casting them to integers. Your call to `int()` is just going to return a `0` for all the ages.

To fix this you need to pass in the string as the parameter to the `int()` call so it converts the `string` to an `int`.

```
response = input("How old are you?")
response = int(response) # converts response to an int
```

You might want to put a try/except block around the conversion to an int to make sure that valid input was entered.

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly. I was wondering what you would have to do to make it reverse like from greatest to least in the same program. I tried to use the reverse function but that just shows an attribute error.

Comment: There's an optional parameter to the `sorted()` function called `reverse` which allows you to specify that it should be sorted reverse. Just change the sorted call to be `sorted(student_ages.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1], reverse=True)`

Answer (score 1):

You have to sort dictionary before `for` cycle. Inside for cycle type of variable `response` is string and you can't sort it.

Use something like this before `for` cycle

```
student_ages_sorted = sorted(student_ages.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
```

Comment: thanks mate, had to change around some things but know it works fine. :)

Comment: you're welcome you can edit my answer and mark it as solved